# Best way to communicate to a remote serial device

Tags: c, linux

As what the title says. I'm trying to communicate to a remote serial device. I know I can do this with socket programming as a client side application.

```
socket_FD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

When I'm connected to remote serial device I can use the read() and write() function to transmit and receive data from the remote serial device.

Receiving:

```
n = read(socket_FD, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0);
```

Transmitting:

```
 n = write(socket_FD, bufftosend, strlen(bufftosend));
```

Now for me to send a data outside of the client side application e.g browser I will utilize pipes(FIFO) and create this pipe in linux. All the data i send will be redirected to the remote serial.

Sending data to the pipe via terminal:

```
echo "THIS IS A COMMAND" > /path/to/FIFO
```

Sending data to the pipe via php:

```
fd = fopen("/path/to/FIFO", "w");
fwrite(fd, "THIS IS A COMMAND");
fclose(fd);
```

My client side application will read this pipe and when it receives a data it will send it to the remote serial.

```
    while((n = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf - 1)) > 0 ){ //fd is the opened pipe.

buf[n - 1] = '\0';

n = write(socket_FD, buf, strlen(buf));
}
```

The remote serial device then will respond with an OK that it receives the data.

This is how I'm communicating with a remote serial device. Is my way of communicating with the remote serial an OK for anyone reading this post?. If not can you please tell me other ways on how can I communicate with the remote serial device.

Thank you...

Comment: Seems OK, but you may want to learn about multiplexing syscalls like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Comment: Is poll better than select?